# DS18b20 BBB problem with reading temp in C code

Tags: c, embedded, beagleboneblack

I can't read the results for temperature from DS18B20 temp sensor installed in BeagleBone black.
I'm using w1.dts like here: http://www.bonebrews.com/temperature-monitoring-with-the-ds18b20-on-a-beaglebone-black/
And my C code is from here: http://bradsmc.blogspot.com/2014/06/c-program-to-read-multiple-ds18b20-1.html

The output in console is looking like that:

```
 Found 1 devices
 <blank line>
 <blank line>
```

I can read the temperature using command

```
cat /sys/devices/w1_bus_master1/28-00000624ec04/w1_slave
```

And my readings are:

```
74 01 4b 46 7f ff 0c 10 55 : crc=55 YES
74 01 4b 46 7f ff 0c 10 55 t=23250
```

I changed already the path code to:

```
char path[] = "/sys/devices/w1_bus_master1/";
sprintf(newDev->devPath, "%s/%s/w1_slave", path, newDev->devID);




int8_t readTemp(struct ds18b20 *d) 
{
 while(d->next != NULL)
    {
    d = d->next;
    int fd = open(d->devPath, O_RDONLY);

    if(fd == -1)
        {
          perror ("Couldn't open the w1 device.");
                 return 1;
        }
    char buf[256];
    ssize_t numRead;
    while((numRead = read(fd, buf, 256)) > 0) 
            {
            strncpy(d->tempData, strstr(buf, "t=") + 0, 4);
            float tempC = strtof(d->tempData, NULL);
            printf("Device: %s  - ", d->devID);
            printf("Temp: %.3f C  ", tempC / 1000);
            printf("%.3f F\n\n", (tempC / 1000) * 9 / 5 + 32);
            }
         close(fd);
        }
 return 0;
}
```

But still function readtemp doesn't show me the actual temperature.

I found that in this function:

```
int8_t findDevices(struct ds18b20 *d)
{
    DIR *dir;
        struct dirent *dirent;
        struct ds18b20 *newDev;
        char path[] = "/sys/devices/w1_bus_master1";
        int8_t i = 0;
        dir = opendir(path);
        if (dir != NULL)
        {

            while ((dirent = readdir(dir)))
            {

                // 1-wire devices are links beginning with 28-
                if(dirent->d_type == DT_LNK && strstr(dirent->d_name, "28-") != NULL)
                {
                    printf("DevId bef");
                    newDev = malloc(sizeof(struct ds18b20));
                    strcpy(newDev->devID, dirent->d_name);
                    // Assemble path to OneWire device
                    sprintf(newDev->devPath, "%s/%s/w1_slave", path, newDev->devID);
                    i++;

                    newDev->next = 0;
                    d->next = newDev;
                    d = d->next;
                }
                else
                {

                }
            }
            (void) closedir(dir);
        }
        else
        {
            perror ("Couldn't open the w1 devices directory");
            return 1;
        }
        return 1;
}
```

The result of:

```
if(dirent->d_type == DT_LNK && strstr(dirent->d_name, "28-") != NULL)
```

When the `d_name = 28-00000624ec04`, the parameters of `dirent->d_type = 4` and `DT_LNK && strstr(dirent->d_name, "28-") = 1` then `dirent->d_type == DT_LNK && strstr(dirent->d_name, "28-")` isn't true

Comment: What does is show then? What's the output of this program when you run it?

Comment: The output is that:  Found 1 devices <blank line> <blank line>

Comment: @Pukacza please add your output to the original post.

Comment: There is a output in my post.

Comment: `If(...)` is a flow-control construct not an expression, it cannot have  a result of NULL.  The expression within the `if(...)` can only be `true` or `false`, no not NULL either.  The only part of that that can yield NULL is the `strstr()` call and that will happen if `dirent->d_name` does not contain `"28-"`.  Use a debugger to see what it contains; it is not possible for use to determine from looking at your code without knowing the input, and using a debugger is a far more sensible means of debugging than posting a question.  The clue is in the name!

Comment: When the `d_name = 28-00000624ec04`, the parameters of `dirent->d_type = 4` and `DT_LNK && strstr(dirent->d_name, "28-") = 1` then `dirent->d_type == DT_LNK && strstr(dirent->d_name, "28-")` isn't true

Comment: Can you suggest something? Couse i don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help someone with that problem couse i solved this.

The original loop looked like that:

```
   if(dirent->d_type == DT_LNK && strstr(dirent->d_name, "28-") != NULL)
```

I changed it to:

```
 if(dirent->d_type == 4)
        {
          if (strstr(dirent->d_name, "28-") != NULL)
          {
```

After that everything is working perfectly.